# VPN working? or not? How do I know?

Tags: pi-2, vpn

I have what appears to be a working VPN on my Pi2 with Raspbian which I can access from an Android mobile phone and a Nexus 7 using PureVPN

What I cannot determine is whether it is actually working and directing traffic through the VPN. The VPN Status shows connected and there is an 'upload' KB and a 'download KB. I can access the internet but when I ask for my IP I am given my WAN IP.

In the log there are three errors:
1, Warning, this configuration may cache passwords - use auth-nocache option to prevent this. (can't find this option)
2. Warning: 'link-mtu' is used inconsistently, local 'link-mtu 1557', remote 'link-mtu 1558'
3. Warning: 'comp-lzo' is present in remote config but missing in local config, remote='comp-lzo'

Is there a way to confirm either via the Pi or on the phone, what the route of data is?

I am surprised that there is a 'remote' too. Where would that be?

```
sudo nano var/log/purevpn.log
Tue Jul  7 20:51:32 2015 PureVPN 2.2.1 arm-linux-gnueabihf [SSL] [LZO2] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [eurephia] [MH] [PF_INET6] [IPv6 payload 20110424-2 (2.2RC2)] built on Dec  1 2014
Tue Jul  7 20:51:32 2015 NOTE: your local LAN uses the extremely common subnet address 192.168.0.x or 192.168.1.x.  Be aware that this might create routing conflicts if you co$
Tue Jul  7 20:51:32 2015 NOTE: PureVPN 2.1 requires '--script-security 2' or higher to call user-defined scripts or executables
Tue Jul  7 20:51:33 2015 Control Channel Authentication: using '/etc/purevpneasy-rsa/keys/ta.key' as a PureVPN static key file
Tue Jul  7 20:51:33 2015 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Tue Jul  7 20:51:33 2015 do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=0, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Tue Jul  7 20:51:33 2015 /sbin/ifconfig tun0 10.8.0.1 pointopoint 10.8.0.2 mtu 1500
Tue Jul  7 20:51:33 2015 GID set to nogroup
Tue Jul  7 20:51:33 2015 UID set to nobody
Tue Jul  7 20:51:33 2015 UDPv4 link local (bound): [AF_INET]192.168.1.200:1194
Tue Jul  7 20:51:33 2015 UDPv4 link remote: [undef]
Tue Jul  7 20:51:33 2015 Initialization Sequence Completed
Tue Jul  7 20:57:58 2015 192.168.1.1:49548 Re-using SSL/TLS context
Tue Jul  7 20:57:58 2015 192.168.1.1:49548 LZO compression initialized
Tue Jul  7 20:57:58 2015 192.168.1.1:49548 WARNING: 'link-mtu' is used inconsistently, local='link-mtu 1558', remote='link-mtu 1557'
Tue Jul  7 20:57:58 2015 192.168.1.1:49548 WARNING: 'comp-lzo' is present in local config but missing in remote config, local='comp-lzo'
Tue Jul  7 20:57:58 2015 192.168.1.1:49548 [makem] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]192.168.1.1:49548
Tue Jul  7 20:57:58 2015 makem/192.168.1.1:49548 MULTI_sva: pool returned IPv4=10.8.0.6, IPv6=e876:fe7e:803e:f076:346b:f576:24bd:cf78
Tue Jul  7 20:58:01 2015 makem/192.168.1.1:49548 send_push_reply(): safe_cap=960
Tue Jul  7 20:58:09 2015 makem/192.168.1.1:49548 Bad LZO decompression header byte: 69
Tue Jul  7 20:58:14 2015 makem/192.168.1.1:49548 Bad LZO decompression header byte: 69
Tue Jul  7 20:58:19 2015 makem/192.168.1.1:49548 Bad LZO decompression header byte: 69

sudo nano /var/log/purevpn-status.log
PureVPN CLIENT LIST
Updated,Tue Jul  7 21:21:07 2015
Common Name,Real Address,Bytes Received,Bytes Sent,Connected Since
ROUTING TABLE
Virtual Address,Common Name,Real Address,Last Ref
GLOBAL STATS
Max bcast/mcast queue length,0
END
```

TIA

Comment: Welcome.  Edit in the output of `ip r` (or `route`); this should provide the info you are looking for.

Comment: You should also post the configuration files. That being said, it appears your VPN is active notwithstanding possible configuration errors, but your routing table has to be adapted so that your traffic flows through the VPN. And it's also possible there is a conflict with your regular LAN IP address range eg 192.168.0.x.

Comment: How would I know if PureVPN is conflicting with LAN IP address

Comment: No one can help you if don't provide the requested information. Here you can [edit] your question and add it.

Comment: The issue is resolved now. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please create an answer about the solution? Then mark the answer as the accepted one with a click on the tick on its left side after two days. That prevents your Question from being shown as an unsolved Post to the community and saves them/us a lot of work. Or if you don't like to share it, please just delete your question.